# Generating alert from applet to the current browser

Tags: java, swing, browser, applet, awt

I have requirement where I need alert the user from applet code depends on some circumstances. Is there any way to give a pop-up with our message?

Comment: I did'nt even get the hint or i may not able find the correct reult

Comment: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog may be what you are looking for. You may also study here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: @Fildor  You should put that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

My comment as answer as proposed:

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog may be what you are looking for. You may also study here: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

I wrote this because you tagged the question with applet and awt. With JavaScript you can also show a MessageBox without Swing, but as you wrote, JOptionPane is the way to go for you.

Answer (score 1):

Ya Fildor your answer is right,i got flashed with same idea,any way we got the answer,
But seems strange to user swing concepts in web application,
I am doing following,

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Your Digital Signature is not registered",
                            "Registration error",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    System.exit(0);
```